Is there a possibility to get a JSON line number from AvroTypeException?
I am working on a JSON-avro validator and it is working just fine. However when the JSON is not valid against avro schema, I only get "Expected int. Got VALUE_STRING" message. This would be fine in small JSON files but not in huge ones.
Is there a way to get a concrete JSON line where the "Expected int. Got VALUE_STRING" was triggered?
Code:
import org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.Decoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse("{\n" +
                "    \"type\" : \"record\",\n" +
                "    \"namespace\" : \"something\",\n" +
                "    \"name\" : \"something\",\n" +
                "    \"fields\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"name\" : \"calendarWeek\",\n" +
                "            \"type\" : [\n" +
                "                \"null\",\n" +
                "                \"int\"\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            \"default\": null\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"name\" : \"year\",\n" +
                "            \"type\" : [\n" +
                "                \"null\",\n" +
                "                \"int\"\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            \"default\": null\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}\n");

        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"calendarWeek\": {\n" +
                "    \"int\": 10\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"year\": {\n" +
                "    \"int\": \"asda\"\n" +
                "}";

        System.out.println(validateJson(json, schema));
    }

public static boolean validateJson(String json, Schema schema) throws Exception {
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);

        try {
            DatumReader reader = new GenericDatumReader(schema);
            Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, din);
            reader.read(null, decoder);
            return true;
        } catch (AvroTypeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}

I am expecting something like "line 3: Expected int. Got VALUE_STRING".
pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>maventest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.16</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

test.json:
{
  "calendarWeek": {
    "int": 10
  },
  "year": {
    "int": "asda"
}


could you please post also your pom.xml or gradle file?

added pom.xml file to the original post

there are no dependencies in your pom? how do you import AvroTypeException to your project?

updated the original post again. No idea why pom.xml file was not getting updated - had to do it manually.

Please also add example json which suppose to reproduce your test case. also please provide some simple Main class which is calling your method

updated original post. Should fail on "year": {
"int": "asda"
},

also please provide some simple Main class which is calling your method –

updated original post.
